# Table/Page manipulation using php

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

i) I have a page with three columns.

Say the page is of the form:

**A**        **B**      **C**

1    4   7

2    5   8

3    6   9

A, B, C are for illustrative purposes.

I need to download only 4,5,6. The links do not have any similarities and do not follow any pattern.

ii) Each column has **n** number of links.

iii) I need to download or print all the links of the second column.

How should I do that using html dom parser? I am able to print all the links.

Comment: We need more info. What do you refer to as 'columns'? (There is no such thing as a <column> HTML tag...). And what do you refer to as a 'page'? A rendered DOM in a browser? Or just an .html file?

Comment: @Pelle ten Cate: A simple html page.

Comment: Could you at least provide a sample of the HTML code generating your so-called page?

Comment: Do you have the possibility to run javascript? Or do you just want to open a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question doesn't provide very much information. Say your page is rendered in a browser that supports javascript, your columns are DIV tags and you can also use javascript on the page, you could select the links using jQuery.

```
var links = [];
$('#columnB a').each(function(index){ // Assuming columnB is the ID of your middle column.
  links.push($(this).href);
});
```

And then pass your variable `links` to PHP using an XmlHttpRequest.

If your page is just an HTML file, you need to use an SGML (for HTML) or an XML (for XHTML) parser. In case you are having XHTML in a file, have a look at XPATH, and the [functionality](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) that PHP has for it.